# How can I run a Windows 11 Lenovo laptop for the longest possible time on a portable power bank?

Tags: windows, laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a Lenovo Ideapad3 running Windows 11 which comes with Lenovo Vantage battery conservation mode where it only charges the laptop battery to about 50 or 60% while plugged in. I do this and then connect to a portable power supply.

I want to know if it's better to turn off conservation mode, let it charge up to say 90% or higher then shut off the power supply and recharge when it gets down to about 20% or so or to do what I am doing now mentioned at the beginning.

Also, how can I conserve power on a Windows 11 laptop except keep the screen as bright as possible?

I work outside in complete darkness so need a bright screen but don't need super fast performance.  By the way my machine has an Nvidia Geforce GTX and AMD Radeon so also wondering if turning off the Nvidia is possible for power saving purposes.

This is my powerbank: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%80%90Amazon%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%80%91NECESPOW-50400mAh-LiFePO4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E9%85%B8%E9%89%84%E3%83%AA%E3%83%81%E3%82%A6%E3%83%A0%E9%9B%BB%E6%B1%A0-%E6%80%A5%E9%80%9F%E5%85%85%E9%9B%BBQC3-0-%E7%B7%8A%E6%80%A5%E3%83%BB%E7%81%BD%E5%AE%B3%E6%99%82%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E7%94%A8%E9%9B%BB%E6%BA%90/dp/B08HZ3G5RK/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=necespow%2B%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E9%9B%BB%E6%BA%90&qid=1673272480&sprefix=necespow%2Caps%2C250&sr=8-5&th=1

Comment: "I work outside in complete darkness so need a bright screen"?? I'd say you do not need a bright screen at all

Comment: I tried already thinking the same and I do.  Plus it illuminates my keyboard as a bonus.

Comment: Keep your battery bet ween 20% and 80% charged.  That's the best practice to keep the battery "good" without having to replace it when it is used a lot.  Two things mostly take up all your power.  Your screen and (if you don't have a  solid sate drive) your hard disk drive.  Move to an SSD if you don't have one.  Possibly turn off any intensive CPU background tasks that you don't need (if you have any)  I know my work often will run arbitrary things that really don't need to be ran and that can cause my laptop to heat up.

Comment: @Dale did you want to write an answer, just copied and pasted?  Otherwise deleting the question.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your battery between 20% and 80% charged. That's the best practice to keep the battery "good" without having to replace it when used a lot. Two things mostly take up all your power. Your screen and (if you don't have a solid-state drive) your hard disk drive. Move to an SSD if you don't have one. Possibly turn off any intensive CPU background tasks you don't need (if you have any). I know my work often will run arbitrary things that don't need to be run, and that can cause my laptop to heat up.